# try catch block still returning exception that is supposed to catch

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to android development and i'm working my way through some sample programs. currently i'm attempting to use a try catch block to prevent the application to crash if the user just presses the created button without entering a number and selecting a route. The try-catch unfortunately is not working as the app keeps crashing and returning the same NumberFormatException. This is a sample of what my code looks like so far.

```
handleSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handleInput = findViewById(R.id.groupInput);
        int numAthletes = Integer.parseInt(handleInput.getText().toString());
        int totalCost;

        try {
            if(dropDown.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Route 1") ||
                    dropDown.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Route 2") ||
                    dropDown.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Route 3") ){
                totalCost = numAthletes * 725;
                displayData.setText(dropDown.getSelectedItem().toString() + " Race Team Fee is  - $" + Integer.toString(totalCost));
            }
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            Log.e( "onClick: ","Empty submission" );

        }

    }
});
```

this is the error that is not being catched.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Comment: Have a look at the line it is thrown from. It is not inside the `try/catch`. In fact there is nothing *inside* the `try/catch` that *could* throw that exception. NB There is no need to call `toString()` on `String` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not catching the right line.

```
int numAthletes = Integer.parseInt(handleInput.getText().toString());
```

That's the line causing the exception, but you've placed it outside of the try{} block.